# error: request for member ‘prev_’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I did a search for this error:

> error: request for member ‘prev_’ in something not a structure or union

And every suggestions were to use `->` but in my case I'm using `->` already.

Here is my code:

```
struct student_record_node
 {

        struct student_record* record_;
        struct student_record_node* next_;
        struct student_record_node* prev_;         
 };

void swap(struct student_record_node** node1, struct student_record_node** node2)

{

struct student_recod_node* prev_;
struct student_recod_node* next_;

          if(*node1->prev_)
          {
                  node1->prev_->next_ = node2;
          }

          if(*node2->prev_)
          {
                  node2->prev_->next_ = node1;
         }
}
```

Comment: please code your coding nicely.

Comment: Try `(*node1)->prev_`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(*node1->prev_)
```

`->` has higher operator precedence than `*`. The above statement is equivalent to:

```
if (*(node1->prev_))
```

Since `node1` does not point to a structure with such a class member, that's the reason you're getting this compilation error. This should be changed to:

```
if((*node1)->prev_)
```

The same fix is needed in the rest of the shown code. For example:

```
node1->prev_->next_ = node2;
```

This probably should be:

```
(*node1)->prev_->next_ = *node2;
```